# How to create an embedded database using Firebird in C#

Tags: c#, database, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to setup an embedded database for my c# application. I try many things but cannot get it working. How can I do it? I mean which files to which folder? I have firebirdclient referenced in my program. Could you please write a summary? thanks in advance...

Comment: what you mean not working? connection problem or what? you have to give more info about your quest.

Comment: "fbembed not found" it says, although I add fbclient.dll and fbembed.dll (renamed version of fbclient.dll) into debug folder.

Comment: did you try copy it to the System32 folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that the `fbembed.dll` is in the same folder as your application source code
2. Add the `fbembed.dll` to your C Sharp application from the **"Add existing item"** menu option (if you have not already done so)
3. Set the output property of this item to **"Copy Always"**.

I have been using `C#` and `fbembed.dll` a lot recently, if you need any more information please reply here.

Answer (score 1):

With little bit older links (older versions of FB), but still valid http://blog.cincura.net/224165-firebird-embedded-and-net/ .

Also you should use proper fbembed.dll and not just rename fbclient.dll.