# How to programmatically create firebird database?

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I have `COMPUTER_WITH_DATABASE` where is superserver firebird (windows) installed.
Now i need to make c# application which will connect to this `COMPUTER_WITH_DATABASE` and create file `.fdb` like for example `database.fdb` to be later able to connect from other computers using for example part of string like:

> COMPUTER_WITH_DATABASE\c:\database.fdb

But how to do it using fb API in c#?

Comment: [How to create an embedded database using Firebird in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725546/how-to-create-an-embedded-database-using-firebird-in-c-sharp)

Comment: [Creating Firebird database programatically (C#/.NET)](http://blog.cincura.net/7968-creating-firebird-database-programatically-c-net/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

with this code you can create a database:

```
...
using FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird;
...

FbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "COMPUTER_WITH_DATABASE";
builder.UserID = "SYSDBA";
builder.Password = "m*******y";
builder.Database = @"c:\database.fdb";
builder.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;

FbConnection.CreateDatabase(builder.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: `FbConnection.CreateDatabase` wants string (basically), not a `Hashtable`, hence this code is not completely correct.

Comment: Thank you, FbConnectionStringBuilder is best to use to create the connection string.

Comment: What if the database already exists. Does 'Create
Database' deletes the old one?

Comment: you can just code  >>>>>>>> string curFile = @"c:\database.fdb";
            if (File.Exists(curFile) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database is already existing!");
            }<<<<<<<<<<< to detect if database is already available hope this help